# why is velocity not decreasing in 2d movement simulation?

Tags: java, swing, math, physics

I am trying to make a program where `object1` movement is warped by the gravity of `object2`. It should get flung. However, for some reason the velocity never decreases or goes negative. I expect for the velocity to change in both directions, but this does not happen. Can anyone tell me why? Here is the code.

Sim.java

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sim extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2669101810074157675L;
    public static final int PREF_W = 800, PREF_H = 600;

    private Mass object1, object2;

    private Sim() {
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        double[] vect1 = {1, 0}, vect2 = {0, 0};
        object1 = new Mass(new Point(PREF_W / 2 - 100, PREF_H / 2 - 100), vect1, 10);
        object2 = new Mass(new Point(PREF_W / 2 + 100, PREF_H / 2 + 100), vect2, 30);
        object2.lock();

        gameTimer.start();

    }

    private Timer gameTimer = new Timer(1000 / 30, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            double[] v = Mass.vector(object1, object2);
            object1.dx += v[0];
            object1.dy += v[1];

            Point p = new Point(
                    (int) (object1.center.x + object1.dx),
                    (int) (object1.center.y + object1.dy)
            );
            object1.center = p;

            System.out.println("[" + object1.center.x + "," + object1.dy + "]");
        }
    });

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.fillOval(
                (int) object1.center.x - (int) object1.radius,
                (int) object1.center.y - (int) object1.radius,
                (int) object1.radius,
                (int) object1.radius
        );

        g2.fillOval(
                (int) object2.center.x - (int) object2.radius,
                (int) object2.center.y - (int) object2.radius,
                (int) object2.radius,
                (int) object2.radius
        );

        g2.drawLine(object1.center.x, object1.center.y, object2.center.x, object2.center.y);


        repaint();

    }

    /* METHODS FOR CREATING JFRAME AND JPANEL */

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gravity Simulation");
                JPanel gamePanel = new Sim();

                frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Mass.java

```java
import java.awt.Point;

public class Mass {

    public static double G = 1f;
    public static double deltaTime = 1;

    public Point center;
    public double mass;
    public double radius;

    public double dx = 0;
    public double dy = 0;

    public boolean locked = false;

    public Mass(Point center, double[] vect, double mass) {
        this.center = center;
        this.dx = vect[0];
        this.dy = vect[1];
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = mass;
    }

    public void lock() {
        this.locked = true;
    }

    public void unlock() {
        this.locked = false;
    }

    public static double distance(Mass obj1, Mass obj2) {

        double dX = obj1.center.x - obj2.center.x;
        double dY = obj1.center.y - obj2.center.y;

        double ans = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dX, 2) + Math.pow(dY, 2));
        return (double) ans;

    }

    public static double force(Mass obj1, Mass obj2) {

        double ans = ((obj1.mass * obj2.mass) / Math.pow(distance(obj1, obj2), 2)) * G;
        return (double) ans;

    }

    public static double[] vector(Mass obj1, Mass obj2) {
        double force = force(obj1, obj2);

        double dX = Math.abs(obj1.center.x - obj2.center.x);
        double dY = Math.abs(obj1.center.y - obj2.center.y);

        double udX = dX / distance(obj1, obj2);
        double udY = dY / distance(obj1, obj2);

        double fx = -(udX * force);
        double fy = -(udY * force);

        double x = obj1.dx + fx / obj1.mass * deltaTime;
        double y = obj1.dy + fy / obj1.mass * deltaTime;

        double[] v = {x, y};
        return v;

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance. I derived my formula from `F = G(m1*m2)/r^2`.

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger

Comment: Situations like this are why debuggers have been invented. It's hard to run those calculations in our heads and spot maybe subtle errors which you are basically asking us to do. It's way easier to step through your code with a debugger and check the values along the way ... eventually you'll find one that doesn't meet your expectations so you investigate why that came to be. That's how you find bugs.